# Server has a valid SSL Cert, Clients only see expired cert, why?

Tags: nginx, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

I have a web server where the active ssl cert (letsencrypt CA) is valid and up-to-date. Nginx is the front.

However, I notice that browsers complain that the cert is expired - they seem to get served or have cached an old version. What's the best way to troubleshoot and resolve this?

Am refusing to contemplate malice outside of misconfiguration, but that's also a possibility.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you reload nginx after updating the certificate? What is the FQDN?

Comment: @MichaelHampton sure I did. Several times. Doesn't yield anything yet. check https://nuchwezi.com

Comment: I get an expired Let's Encrypt certificate. Are you sure you renewed it? How do you know? How do you know you reloaded nginx?

Comment: A1: "You have an existing certificate that has exactly the same domains or certificate name you requested and isn't close to expiry." that's LE's log. And yes, I've reloaded, killed and restarted nginx. It's not helping.

Comment: All i can say is to check your nginx and Let's encrypt configuration, then. You didn't provide them (and you should have).

Comment: @MichaelHampton if LE's auto-renew has worked as is for my other sites and I've not touched the nginx configs from what's worked before, you suspect it's the configs that are flawed?

Comment: Hi, that happened to me once, I remembered it was because even if you reloaded/stoped NGINX, it wasn’t restarting/reloading correctly. I had to stop NGINX then run a `ps aux | grep -i nginx` command and kill all the processes related with NGINX and then start NGINX...

Comment: Thanks all. I've found the flaw to be in how LE was renewing the certs - after following the suggestions to purge/reset completely (see here https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/correct-way-to-completely-remove-issued-certificate-s-for-a-domain/7409/11), I managed to recreate the cert anew, and it now works!

Comment: Can you post the steps you followed as an answer, in case it helps someone else?

Comment: If you gave the name concerned people could have helped you faster and more easily.

Answer (score 0):

Clearing the Let's Encrypt certs out completely, and creating them anew solved the problem on two servers with the same issue. The basic steps:

1. Delete the offending certs - `letsencrypt-auto delete`, which on some flavors is `certbot delete`
2. `rm -rf` the physical files for the offending domain. Something like...

   ```
   rm -rf /etc/letsencrypt/live/${DOMAIN}
   rm -rf /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/${DOMAIN}.conf
   rm -rf /etc/letsencrypt/archive/${DOMAIN}
   ```
3. Obtain the domain cert anew - `letsencrypt-auto certonly --standalone -d {DOMAIN}`
4. Reload web server.

Comment: If you still run `letsencrypt-auto` then your copy of certbot is woefully out of date and desperately needs to be updated. You should be on at least 0.21.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! My life requires that sometimes I dwell longer in the stone ages ;-) I'll surely update.

Comment: There are critical security issues prior to 0.21. You should update immediately as renewal may not work with older versions.

Comment: Removing the certificate before getting a new one seems a risky step, in case the renewal does not happen for whatever reason...